# Remove Vertical Lines from AMCHARTS Grid and keep Horizontal lines

Tags: charts, amcharts

My question is about a specific Graphs and Charts Building Tool call AMCHARTS. I am using their live editor to build a Graph, and I need to remove the vertical lines (leave the horizontal lines only) from the chart grid.

Is it possible to do so?

thanks,

Answer (score 13):

Just in case someone is still looking for the answer:

```
//disable horizontal lines    
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 0;

//disable vertical lines
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 0;
```

Answer (score 11):

just change "categoryAxis"

```
"categoryAxis": {
     "gridThickness": 0
},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a solution on amCharts 4 use the following:

```
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
```

See official docs for [disabling certain elements](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Disabling_certain_elements)

Comment: your solution is hiding both - vertical and horizontal. But the request is about hiding only vertical lines.

Answer (score 3):

For removing the horizontal lines in the grid ...

```
   "valueAxes":{
                  "gridThickness":0
               },
```

Comment: It's valueAxes.

Comment: @user3384672 It's not working for me. It is removing the whole graph.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for am5charts, then add

```
yAxis.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({
      strokeWidth: 0,
      visible:false
    });


xAxis.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({
      location: 0,
      strokeWidth: 0,
      visible:false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did some research, I'm posting the answer so that other can benefit.  This option is in the "Category Axis -> Grid and Fills" Section.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good anseer by adding one more category or value axis to our charts:

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2866